# Holes in polygons using encoded polylines

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We're seeing conflicting documentation about this, but is it possible to use encoded polylines to render complex polygons (those with holes/donuts)?

I would think reversing the winding direction should work, but we're being told by a developer that encoded polylines do not support this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What language you're programming in? Where's the code?

Comment: JavaScript....extJS framework.

Comment: Can you provide anexample? Have you tried encoding the outer boundary and inner hole separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, you need to encode/decode the inner and outer paths separately.

```
var donut = new google.maps.Polygon({
             paths: [google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedOP),
             google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedIP)],
             strokeColor: "#0000FF",
             strokeOpacity: 0.8,
             strokeWeight: 2,
             fillColor: "#FF0000",
             fillOpacity: 0.35
           });
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  var encodedOP = "~a|mEsmnd\\{av@dpEa~s@njRgyo@~l^gxi@|hi@wbb@tpr@abYdyy@eaOfy~@slDzjaArlDzjaAdaOfy~@`bYdyy@vbb@tpr@fxi@|hi@fyo@~l^`~s@njRzav@dpEzav@epE`~s@ojRfyo@_m^fxi@}hi@vbb@upr@`bYeyy@daOgy~@rlD{jaAslD{jaAeaOgy~@abYeyy@wbb@upr@gxi@}hi@gyo@_m^a~s@ojR{av@epE";
  var encodedIP = "pp`mEwaa_\\lpZqgBlpZpgBpnYvtH`lW`vNtkT|cTzpPzwXn`L`l\\``Gb|^xuA|d`@yuA|d`@a`Gb|^o`L`l\\{pPzwXukT|cTalW`vNqnYvtHmpZpgBmpZqgBqnYwtHalWavNukT}cT{pP{wXo`Lal\\a`Gc|^yuA}d`@xuA}d`@``Gc|^n`Lal\\zpP{wXtkT}cT`lWavNpnYwtH";
  var donut = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedOP),
      google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedIP)
    ],
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  donut.setMap(map);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Path encoding of Google Maps is able to one dimension array, not two dimensions array (I mean Array<Array> is not possible).

However drawing a polygon that has hole needs two dimensions array.
(You maybe know)

So code should be like this:

```
var exteriorBoundary = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decode("<encoded polyline string>";
var hole = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decode("<another encoded polyline string>";

var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [exteriorBoundary, hole],
  map: map,
  ...
});
```